# JAVA: Nesting in Iterator in a public class

Tags: java, iterator, nested

So for a school project, I need to make a private method that implements the Iterator interface. I have my method SetIterator, and it looks like this:

```
  private class SetIterator implements Iterator<T> {
  private T[] items; 
  private int count; 
  private int current; 

  private SetIterator(T[] elements, int size) {
     items = elements;
     count = size;
     current = 0;
  }

  private boolean hasNext() {
     return (current < count);
  }

  private T next() {
     if (!hasNext()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }

     return items[current++];
  }
```

However, I am not able to compile because I'm getting this error message:

```
ArraySet.java:311: error: next() in ArraySet.SetIterator cannot implement next() in Iterator
  private T next() {
            ^
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
where T,E are type-variables:
T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in class ArraySet
E extends Object declared in interface Iterator
ArraySet.java:307: error: hasNext() in ArraySet.SetIterator cannot implement hasNext() in Iterator
private boolean hasNext() {
                  ^
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

I've never really run into this before, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make `next()` `public`: `public T next() {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterator is an interface. Hence, its methods are public. You cannot implement the method and make it private.

Change the visibility to `public`.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
  return (current < count);
}
```

Comment: I guess I just figured that having a public method in a private class would violate encapsulation somehow. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

The error is fairly self explanatory: `next` and `hasNext` are public in `Iterator` so you can't make them private. Change `private` to `public` and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because you cannot assign a "weaker" privilege to a method you override from a super class or implement from an interface.

Since methods defined on an interface in Java are `public` by default, the Java compiler prevents us from implementing these methods with a weaker access privilege such as `protected` or `private`. The reason it does so is because of an inherent principle of object oriented programming - an instance of a subclass should be generally usable where an instance of its super class is expected (checkout the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) to get a better understanding of this concept).

To sum up, declare `SetIterator`'s `hasNext()` and `next()` methods as public, since they implement the `Iterator` interface's methods.

Answer (score 0):

you would not have encountered this Issue if you would have known the rules for Overrding inr Java .

Try to google on overriding rules in Java. start from here : 
http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/09/what-is-rules-of-overloading-and-overriding-in-java.html

Always remember the thumb rule : Never reduce the scope of method , you can always increase the scope of method while overriding it , but can never decerese it.